# Unable to install GDAL in python 3 using pip (clang failed with exit status 1)

Tags: clang, gdal, python-3.4

After running `sudo pip3.4 install gdal` from terminal (Mac OS X Mavericks) I obtain an error message saying that the `'col_port.h'` file was not found and displaying the following error: `command '/user/bin/clang/ failed with exit status 1` (the full message is below).

I have gdal 1.11 (the complete framework version downloaded from kingchaos.com) and the most recent version of the Xcode command line tools -Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)

---

Here is the error that I get  after running the `sudo pip3.4 install gdal` command:

```
/usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -Werror=declaration-after-statement -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -I../../port -I../../gcore -I../../alg -I../../ogr/ -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/include/python3.4m -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.11/include -c extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/extensions/gdal_wrap.o
extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:2230:11: warning: explicitly assigning a variable of type 'int' to itself [-Wself-assign]
                    res = SWIG_AddCast(res);
                    ~~~ ^              ~~~
extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:2233:11: warning: explicitly assigning a variable of type 'int' to itself [-Wself-assign]
                    res = SWIG_AddCast(res);
                    ~~~ ^              ~~~
extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:2535:22: warning: unused variable 'swig_empty_runtime_method_table' [-Wunused-variable]
  static PyMethodDef swig_empty_runtime_method_table[] = { {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL} };/* Sentinel */
                     ^
extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:2855:10: fatal error: 'cpl_port.h' file not found
#include "cpl_port.h"
         ^

3 warnings and 1 error generated.
error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 4):

The solution was to use `homebrew` and, after that, run `pip3.4`

```
brew install GDAL
```

and, once installed,

```
pip3.4 install gdal
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, i tried all the other solutions and nothing, but this one worked like a charm D:

Answer (score 1):

Had this problem today. Installed GDAL with brew and it failed with pip3. The solution was to make sure that the version you try to install with pip is the same as homebrew has installed.

So first install gdal with homebrew using

```
brew install gdal
```

You should be able to see the version that is being installed during installation. If you have already installed gdal before you can check the version with:

```
brew info gdal
```

For me this showed that the version of gdal brew installed for me was: 2.4.4
So then you can install the correct version with pip using

```
pip3 install gdal==2.4.4
```

This finally worked for me.